# move tomcat webapp from server to localhost

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web-applications, server, tomcat7

We, in the organization, have a web app currently running on a server. I want to move this app to my local machine where I can customize and edit files safely. I copied the app directory, let us name it 'mproject', to my local machine and added it to the webapps folder of tomcat. However, the app did not work. Tomcat gives me this error `FAIL - Application at context path [/mproject] could not be started` What parameters shall I modify in order to run this app on my local tomcat?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: We can't possibly know. Read the documentation of this app. Read its source code. Ask the people who developed it.

Comment: Check each line of each log file and probably you will find what to modify.

Comment: @JBNizet, Most probably, there shall be some XML files to be edited. I am asking which of those.

Answer (score 1):

Check the log files in the folder `logs`. Tomcat has probably left a lot of details there why it couldn't start the app.

Note: Many of the files in the app will have been compiled from a source project. Try to get a copy of that and use tools to build the app from the sources instead of trying to modify the compiled result.

Note 2: You (or your company) didn't develop the web app, you're not always allowed to modify files as you like. Please check the license of the product, first, and get approval from your manager.

Comment: This is the problem. The app is a vended app. We have no control on the source.

Comment: You're planning to change an app your bought? Do you have a license to do that?

Comment: not changing the source. Only UI changes on html and JS files.

Comment: The vendor has a copyright on every file that they install on your harddisk. Please get approval for this from a manager before you get in trouble.

Comment: The approval is provided. However, work will be in my local machine. It is kind of experimentation and exploration. Anything meant for production will be discussed and verified properly.

Comment: Okay. Then look into the logs and let us know in a new question when you find something in there that you don't understand.

Comment: just wait for some time. I will prepare another post just soon. Thanks for your great interest @Aaron, really appreciate!

Comment: here it is:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55359943/tomcat-versions-conflicts-and-problems-of-compatibility-between-apache-7-35-and