# Tomcat versions conflicts and problems of compatibility between apache 7.35 and windows 10

Tags: tomcat, server, tomcat7, compatibility, tomcat8

## Introduction

This post is related to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55334601/4412324). I was desperately trying to migrate an app from my organization server to my local machine just to explore the code and get my hands on. This is my first time getting familiar with Tomcat and java servlets things, hence it is a newbie talking to you here.  My tries was with tomcat version 7.0.93. and tomcat 8.0.35. With tomcat 8.0.35, the app opens but crashes in the login screen, I guess. With tomcat 7.0.93, the app did not start at all, the logs was giving me a memory shortage errors. This morning, I double checked the version of tomcat in the server and installed the same one in my local machine. That version was 7.0.35. I, then, moved my app to webapps folder, and the app launches! I am facing delays and slowness. However, I will try to discover and explore.

## My questions here

1. Is there compatibility problems so that if an app is running with tomcat 7, then tomcat cannot be upgraded to tomcat 8 or even 9.
2. I am facing too many problems with this version with windows 10. Most of them are administration related. For example, the server needs to be stopped from the command line using `taskkill /pid $$$$ /f` command. This is really annoying. Is there any way to make this version of tomcat, tomcat 7.0.35, compatibly and friendly with windows 10?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: compatibly and friendly with windows 10 => It is already.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there compatibility problems so that if an app is running with
>   tomcat 7, then tomcat cannot be upgraded to tomcat 8 or even 9.

Choosing tomcat version is based on **JDK version**,

please refer https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

If you are planning to **upgrade** tomcat: refer

https://www.mrc-productivity.com/docs/m-power-admin/instructions-for-upgrading-to-tomcat-9

> the server needs to be stopped from the command line

Just **double-click** startup.bat and shutdown.bat from Tomcat installation folder.